# Calculating the mean for 4th quartile for multiple columns at an interval

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm quite new to Python so this might be an easy question.

I'm trying to compare peaks in dataframe between columns over multiple regular intervals, the problems is that there is a delay in  the peaks between the columns. The most logical solution to me would be to take the mean of the 4th quartile for each column.

My data looks something like this

```
    0      1     2 
0  -0.2   0.4  -0.5
1   0.3   0.8   0.4 
2  -0.5   0.4   0.7
3   0.4  -0.6   0.5
etc.
```

I would like to get mean values of the 4th quartile over every 18000 rows. But i'm already stuck before trying to incorporate the intervals, as when i try `np.percentile(df,[100])` I only get a single value and I'm not sure if this is the highest value or the mean of the 4th quartile.

The outcome I had in mind would look something like this

```
               1    2    3
    0-18000   0.8  0.9  0.8
18001-36000   1.2  0.9  0.9
etc.
```

Comment: is your data length multiple of 18000?

Comment: by `-0,2`, do you actually mean `-0.2`?

Comment: @PierreD You're right it is written as a . in the real dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile), there are only 3 quartiles, which are cut-points separating the data evenly into four parts.

The upper quartile corresponds to the 75th percentile, and is a single value (not an interval).

Now, to get that threshold (the upper quartile) for each group of `18_000` rows, a simple way is:

```py
by = 18_000
df.groupby(df.index // by).apply(pd.DataFrame.quantile, .75)
```

### Example

```py
# setup (note that in this case we don't have a multiple of 18_000,
# but that doesn't matter; the last group is simply smaller)
n = 100_000
by = 18_000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 1, (n, 3)))

out = df.groupby(df.index // by).apply(pd.DataFrame.quantile, .75)

>>> out
0.75         0         1         2
0     0.750901  0.745639  0.750561
1     0.750213  0.749832  0.755330
2     0.750073  0.751385  0.752866
3     0.750258  0.754985  0.756654
4     0.741512  0.749209  0.748945
5     0.744568  0.746684  0.749249
```

### Note

If you'd like to see where the values come from:

```py
up = df.groupby(df.index // by).size().cumsum()
ab = np.c_[np.r_[0, up[:-1]], up - 1]
out = out.set_axis([f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in ab])

>>> out
0.75                0         1         2
0-17999      0.750901  0.745639  0.750561
18000-35999  0.750213  0.749832  0.755330
36000-53999  0.750073  0.751385  0.752866
54000-71999  0.750258  0.754985  0.756654
72000-89999  0.741512  0.749209  0.748945
90000-99999  0.744568  0.746684  0.749249
```

### Second interpretation: averages of the upper quart

If instead, you are looking for the average values above the upper quartile (instead of the threshold itself):

```py
def upper_quartile_avg(g):
    return g[g >= g.quantile(.75)].mean()

gb = df.groupby(df.index // by)
up = gb.size().cumsum()
ab = np.c_[np.r_[0, up[:-1]], up - 1]
out = gb.apply(upper_quartile_avg).set_axis([f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in ab])

>>> out
                    0         1         2
0-17999      0.875084  0.871676  0.876100
18000-35999  0.873781  0.876534  0.878645
36000-53999  0.874558  0.873917  0.876843
54000-71999  0.876250  0.877212  0.876409
72000-89999  0.868888  0.874781  0.874565
90000-99999  0.871974  0.873183  0.876113
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
#generate random data
#note that len(df) is multiple of 18000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(18000*4, 3))
```

`df` has shape `72000 rows × 3 columns`.

```
#reshape the data to group rows of the same interval
X = df.values.reshape(-1, 18_000, df.shape[1])
```

`X` is a `np.array` of shape `(4, 18000, 3)`.

```
#compute quartiles for every interval and for every column
quartiles = np.quantile(X, q=0.75, axis=1)
```

`quartiles` is a `np.array` of shape `(4, 3)`, where 4 is the number of intervals, while 3 is the number of variables in the starting dataframe.

```
#mask (with nan) the values lower than the specific quartile
X[X<quartiles.reshape(quartiles.shape[0],1,quartiles.shape[1])] = np.nan

#compute the mean excluding nans and rebuild the dataframe
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.nanmean(X, axis=1))
```

`df_2` contains the means of the 4th quartile values for variables 0, 1 and 2 (columns) in specific intervals (rows). My out-cam:

```
           0           1           2
0   0.876339    0.877293    0.874126
1   0.872108    0.877760    0.871988
2   0.877431    0.875684    0.874172
3   0.876306    0.877515    0.872103
```